# A traffic light (1 "light" composed of 3 lights) or A SET of traffic lights (3 lights considered individually)?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, grammatical-number, british-english

Which is idiomatic in British and American English, when talking about a single post that contains 3 lights, red, yellow and green? *A* traffic light or *A SET* of traffic lights?

Dictionaries seem equivocal about this.

- The *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English* lists only the plural noun [*traffic lights*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/traffic-lights). This implies that each of the red, yellow and green lights are considered separately.
- The *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary* lists a singular form [*traffic light*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/traffic-light?q=traffic%20light), with a note that says "(**also** traffic lights [plural])", and a definition that says "**a set of** lights that controls the traffic on a road." Based on this definition, the singular form seems to be able to refer to all three lights together.
- The *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary* would beg to differ. Like the OALD, it also lists the singular form [*traffic light*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/traffic-light?q=traffic%2Blight), but the definition says "**one of a set** of red, yellow, and green lights that control the movement of vehicles", meaning that a "light" really means a single light, not a set of three lights.

There have also been multiple spirited online discussions. Two Wordreference threads ([1](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/traffic-light-or-traffic-lights.2861849/) and [2](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/traffic-lights-a-traffic-light-a-set-of-traffic-lights.2246526/)) seem to arrive at the conclusion that *traffic light* is idiomatic in the US, while *traffic lights* is in the Commonwealth. More users from [italki](https://www.italki.com/en/post/question-503528) seem to agree with this intuition, too.

If it is indeed the case that *traffic light* is American English and *traffic lights* is Commonwealth English, I guess the only thing left is confirmation from an authoritative source, preferably some sort of book or guideline from a transport(ation) authority.

Comment: Other terms are "traffic light signals" (used in [UK regulations](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/light-signals-controlling-traffic)), and "traffic light head" (for the [actual unit](https://www.transportsupport.co.uk/products/site-safety/traffic-light-systems/traffic-light-head-pedestrian-call-points/300mm-red-green-led/), with one or multiple lights). Not sure there's a strongly preferred term.

Comment: @StuartF Looks like one of the three lights can be called a "signal" too.

Comment: In isolation , both are valid. Either **may** become invalid when used in a Sentence which requires the other. More-over , usage will vary with the "car driver" , "equipment manufacturer" , "maintenance guy" , "road crosser" , "traffic controller" , Etc !

Comment: I think of a traffic signal as having (at least) three lights, green, yellow, red, and maybe red and green arrows as well. Plus orange hands and white stick figures.

Comment: [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/traffic-light?q=+traffic+light) [CALD] suggests the usage you select is [UK]; later it [now CACD] has 'a set of red, yellow, and green lights that control the movement of vehicles at a point where two or more streets meet' [US pronunciation only offered]. Wikipedia doesn't commit itself in the running text in [this article](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_light), though the accompanying diagram clearly has 'traffic light' = 'set of lights set in a single housing'. Webster's ...

Comment: and Penguin/Random House support the 'set of 3 / 4 /... (single housing)' sense as the default in the US.

Comment: I've only ever heard "traffic light" in the US, when referring to a single traffic-control do-dad.  But many intersections have several do-dads.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you misread the "UK" part. The two UK-only definitions refer to a ranking system, not literal traffic light posts.

Comment: No; the pronunciation of the section is a guide to region. Notice the later 'US' pronunciation accompanying the 'boxed set' sense.

Answer (score 1):

The California Driver’s Handbook calls the set of lights a *traffic signal.*  A traffic signal has lights of different colors:

> A yellow traffic signal light means CAUTION.

In conversation, a passenger would probably warn the driver by saying “There’s a light up ahead.” “Turn left at the light” would be idiomatic in the United States, as would “Turn left at the third traffic light.”

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided from the dictionaries and online discussions, it seems that there is some regional variation in the idiomatic usage of "traffic light" and "traffic lights." While it might not be possible to find a definitive answer on this issue, we can infer from the information available that:

1. "Traffic light" tends to be more idiomatic in American English,
   referring to a single post containing the red, yellow, and green
   lights.
2. "Traffic lights" seems to be more common in British and Commonwealth
   English, where it can refer to a single post containing the three
   lights or multiple sets of lights at an intersection.

It's important to note that context plays a significant role in understanding the intended meaning. In most cases, speakers of either American or British English should be able to understand what is meant, regardless of whether the term is used in singular or plural form.

However, it is worth noting that language is always evolving, and what might be considered idiomatic today might change over time. To get a more authoritative answer, you could consult transport authorities or style guides from both regions.

Comment: "you could consult transport authorities or style guides" I wish. One of the reasons I frequent this site is to offload the task of accessing less accessible material (expensive, hidden behind paywalls, obscure, etc.) onto people who are more resourceful or better at researching than I am. Trying to find a good source as broke thirdworlder is no mean feat.